# how to dynamically generate text boxes on selecting option values from multi select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multi-select

I have a Multi Select dropdown, from where users selects multiple items.

On the basis of option values  selection, dynamic Textbox should generate in the same form.

On selecting single option, 3 textbox should generate.
1st textbox showing values of the selected option
2nd textbox showing text of the selected option
3rd textbox showing null.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body align="center">
    <input type="text" value="some text"/>
    <select id="multiple" multiple="multiple" style="width: 120px;height: 120px;">
      <option value="1" >Ashutosh</option>option value="6">Jems Bond</option>
      <option value="7">Danial Crack</option> option value="8">Dan Brown</option>
      <option value="9">Angilina Jolly</option>
    </select>
    <script>
      function displayVals() { 
        var multipleValues = $("#multiple").val() || [];
        $("input").val(multipleValues);
      }
      $("select").change(displayVals);displayVals();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you thought about formatting your question? See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Sir it is not formating. Can you please format it properly. It should look like Code.

Comment: yeah i read it. Now i understood. Thank you

Comment: I have formatted with new lines, if that is a direct copy/past of your HTML, there are errors, such as the missing `<` at the start of some of the options

Comment: @Onheiron Problem was "to check correctly before pasting  code from IDE "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i have made complete solution for your query. please check demo link as shown below:

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7a

**HTML**

```
<form id="frm">
  <select id="multiple" multiple="multiple" style="width: 120px;height: 120px;">
    <option value="1" >
      Ashutosh
    </option>
    <option value="6">
      Jems Bond
    </option>
    <option value="7">
      Danial Crack
    </option>
    <option value="8">
      Dan Brown
    </option>
    <option value="9">
      Angilina Jolly
    </option>
  </select>
  <div id="result">
  </div>
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
    $("#multiple").change(function() {
        var multipleValues = $("#multiple").val() || "";
        var result = "";
        if (multipleValues != "") {
            var aVal = multipleValues.toString().split(",");
            $.each(aVal, function(i, value) {
                result += "<div>";
                result += "<input type='text' name='opval" + (parseInt(i) + 1) + "' value='" + value.trim() + "'>";
                result += "<input type='text' name='optext" + (parseInt(i) + 1) + "' value='" + $("#multiple").find("option[value=" + value + "]").text().trim() + "'>";
                result += "<input type='text' name='option" + (parseInt(i) + 1) + "' value=''>";
                result += "</div>";
            });


        }
        //Set Result
        $("#result").html(result);

    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#multiple{
  margin-bottom:10px;
  border:1px solid #333;
  background:#efefef;
  color:#000;
}
#result input{
  margin-left:5px;
  border:1px solid #333;
  background:#a4c4f4;
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7a

Comment: sir you are very talented person. Thankyou sir. Exactly i want like this.

Comment: i have a new doubt. I think only you can solve my problem. please click this link->> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421102/how-to-calculate-values-with-the-refrence-to-multi-select-drop-down-and-textbox/12421663#12421663