# how to calculate values with the refrence to multi select drop down and textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html form having-
                 1 multi select dropdown :Where users select the name_of_employee.
                 1 Textbox               : Where users enter the Total price.
After entering the total price in textbox, one small calculation should happen and its result should be shown in third  dynamically generated textbox.
                Calculation will Be:
     result={ total_price_entered_in_textbox /  total_option_selected_from_Selectbox}

My problem is that "**how can i do this calculation and show its result in the dynamically created textbox?**". (Please run my code below).
               In simple i am implementing "Diving total amounts in the equal parts to all the selected employee from Multiselect drop down."

```
                            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
              <style>#multiple{
              margin-bottom:10px;
              border:1px solid #333;
              background:#efefef;
              color:#000;
            }
            #result input{
              margin-left:5px;
              border:1px solid #333;
              background:#a4c4f4;
              margin-top:5px;
            }
              </style>
              <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body align="center">
            <form id="frm">
              <select id="multiple" multiple="multiple" style="width: 120px;height: 120px;">
                <option value="1" >
                  Ashutosh
                </option>
                <option value="6">
                  Jems Bond
                </option>
                <option value="7">
                  Danial Crack
                </option>
                <option value="8">
                  Dan Brown
                </option>
                <option value="9">
                  Angilina Jolly
                </option>
              </select>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="target" name="total_price" size="13" id="" style="background-color:orange;font-size: 22px;color: blue"/> <!--User will  enter the total_price in this textbox -->
              <div id="result">
              </div>
            </form>
            <script>
               $(function()
             {



                $("#multiple").change(function()
                {
                    var multipleValues = $("#multiple").val() || "";
                    var result = "";
                    if (multipleValues != "") {
                        var aVal = multipleValues.toString().split(",");
                        var count = $("#multiple :selected").length;

                           $('#target').keyup(function()
                              {
                                  var price = $(this).val();
                                  var price_per_head= price/count ;
                                  alert("result="+price_per_head)
                               });

                        $.each(aVal, function(i, value) {
                            result += "<div>";
                            result += "<input type='text' name='opval" + (parseInt(i) + 1) + "' value='" + value.trim() + "'>";
                            result += "<input type='text' name='optext" + (parseInt(i) + 1) + "' value='" + $("#multiple").find("option[value=" + value + "]").text().trim() + "'>";
                             result += "<input type='text' name='option" + (parseInt(i) + 1) + "' value='' '>";
                            result += "</div>";



                        });
                    }
                    //Set Result
                    $("#result").html(result);

                });
            });



            calculator = function()
            {
                                //I would select it by once the user has selected it, add a active class to it
                              var firstDropdown = $('#drop.active') .val(),
                                  price = $('textarea').val(),
                                  result = firstDropdown / price;

                              //I'd then have a container that would hold the dynamic textarea
                              $('#container').html('<textarea class="eval">' + result + '</textarea>')
             };


            </script> 
            </body>
            </html>
```

Hope someone will help me for this.

Thanking you
-Ashutosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Demo : http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7a/2

JS

```
$(function() {
                $("#multiple").change(function() {
                    var multipleValues = $("#multiple").val() || "";
                    var result = "";
                    if (multipleValues != "") {
                        var aVal = multipleValues.toString().split(",");
                        var count = $("#multiple :selected").length;
                        $.each(aVal, function(i, value) {
                            result += "<div>";
                            result += "<input type='text' name='opval" + (parseInt(i) + 1) + "' value='" + value.trim() + "'>";
                            result += "<input type='text' name='optext" + (parseInt(i) + 1) + "' value='" + $("#multiple").find("option[value=" + value + "]").text().trim() + "'>";
                             result += "<input type='text' name='option" + (parseInt(i) + 1) + "' value='' '>";//result should display in this textbox .i.e (result= total_price/count )
                            result += "</div>";
                              alert("Number of selected Names="+count);
                        });
                    }
                    //Set Result
                    $("#result").html(result);

                });

  $("#toal_price").blur(function(){
        var multipleValues = $("#multiple").val() || "";
        var total_price = $("#toal_price").val();
        var aVal = multipleValues.toString().split(",");
        var count = $("#multiple :selected").length;
        if (multipleValues != "") {
          $.each(aVal, function(i, value) {
            var price = total_price / count;   
            $("input[name=option"+(parseInt(i) + 1)+"]").val(price);
          });
        }  

  });
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="frm">
              <select id="multiple" multiple="multiple" style="width: 120px;height: 120px;">
                <option value="1" >
                  Ashutosh
                </option>
                <option value="6">
                  Jems Bond
                </option>
                <option value="7">
                  Danial Crack
                </option>
                <option value="8">
                  Dan Brown
                </option>
                <option value="9">
                  Angilina Jolly
                </option>
              </select>
                <br/>
              <input type="text" id="toal_price" name="total_price" size="13" id="" style="background-color:orange;font-size: 22px;color: blue"/> <!--User will  enter the total_price in this textbox -->
              <div id="result">
              </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: one new doubt is arises. I want to do Dynamic validation to the  generated text box. Such that , the total sum of all the dynamic generated textbox should be equal to the value of total_price(static textbox).

Comment: i have posted my new doubt here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471823/how-to-validate-dynamically-generated-textbox-with-reference-to-another-textbox   Please help me sir.

Comment: on which event do you want validation ?

Comment: i have a small doubt: After filling all the data in the above Dynamic form, insertion in Db is happening. But when i click on the Edit button ,then i am selecting the previous selected option which should show me the dynamic values in the those 3 text-box.But this is not happening. I do not know why? But if i select it again manually then it is working fine.(i am using this form http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7a/2)-same as u taught me

Comment: Just nw i solved it. by adding .... }//Set autoresult$("#autoresult").html(autoresult);}) .change(); .... at the end of the first function.

Answer (score 0):

I wont generate the whole code for you, but I can give you some tips, basically, with jquery, you'd do something like this.

```
calculator = function(){
    //I would select it by once the user has selected it, add a active class to it
  var firstDropdown = $('#drop.active') .val(),
      price = $('textarea').val(),
      result = firstDropdown / price;

  //I'd then have a container that would hold the dynamic textarea
  $('#container').html('<textarea class="eval">' + result + '</textarea>')
};
```

If I've helped you start this in any way, please be sure to vote it up :) if you want to call the function, just use calculator(); on the onclick event of a button.

Comment: i already generating dynamic textbox.(Please run my above html code,you will understand my exact problem.). I want to show the result in the third textbox(Dynamically generated textbox). Result will be (value enter in the textbox/count)