# how to validate dynamically generated textbox with reference to another textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Please check  [this-click here](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7a/2) working demo before reading this question.
I am generating  3 textboxes (Dynamically  on key-up event),  if users provide any value to  my parent textbox(this is static txtbox). Now i want to do Validation

I have a text-box(say parent text-box), if user enters any number in it then 3 text box are generating dynamically.(namely id,username, amount)
Now i want to do a j query validation on it, such that the sum of all the entered amount values should be equal to the Values entered in the parent text box.

```
                                <!DOCTYPE html>
                                <html>
                                <head>
                                  <style>#multiple{
                                  margin-bottom:10px;
                                  border:1px solid #333;
                                  background:#efefef;
                                  color:#000;
                                }
                                #autoresult input{
                                  margin-left:5px;
                                  border:1px solid #333;
                                  background:#a4c4f4;
                                  margin-top:5px;
                                }
                                  </style>
                                  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
                                </head>
                                <body align="center">
                               <form id="frm">
                 Please select your friends: <select id="multiple" multiple="multiple" style="width: 120px;height: 120px;">
                    <option value="1" >
                      Ashutosh
                    </option>
                    <option value="6">
                      Jems Bond
                    </option>
                    <option value="7">
                      Danial Crack
                    </option>
                    <option value="8">
                      Dan Brown
                    </option>
                    <option value="9">
                      Angilina Jolly
                    </option>
                  </select>
                  <br/>
                  <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" size="33" id="" placeholder="Enter Total Budget Amount" style="background-color:orange;font-size: 22px;color: blue"/>

                  <!--User will  enter the amount in this textbox -->
                  <div id="autoresult">
                  </div>
                </form>

                                <script>
                                  $(function() {
                    $("#multiple").change(function() {
                        var multipleValues = $("#multiple").val() || "";
                        var autoresult = "";
                        if (multipleValues != "") {
                            var aVal = multipleValues.toString().split(",");
                            var count = $("#multiple :selected").length;
                            $.each(aVal, function(i, value) {
                                autoresult += "<div>";
                                autoresult += "<input type='text' readonly='true' name='opval" + (parseInt(i) + 1) + "' value='" + value.trim() + "'>";
                                autoresult += "<input type='text' readonly='true' name='optext" + (parseInt(i) + 1) + "' value='" + $("#multiple").find("option[value=" + value + "]").text().trim() + "'>";
                                autoresult += "<input type='text' name='option" + (parseInt(i) + 1) + "' value='' ' placeholder='Enter my amount' size='120'> <p>Want a validation for this textbox</p>   <font color='red'>Error SUM of all dynamic generated textbox values exceeds the total budget amount <font>"

                                ; //autoresult should display in this textbox .i.e (autoresult= amount/count )
                                autoresult += "</div>"; 
                            });
                        }
                        //Set autoresult
                        $("#autoresult").html(autoresult);

                    });

                    $("#amount").keyup(function() {
                        var multipleValues = $("#multiple").val() || "";
                        var amount = $("#amount").val();
                        var aVal = multipleValues.toString().split(",");
                        var count = $("#multiple :selected").length;
                        if (multipleValues != "")
                        {
                               $.each(aVal, function(i, value) {
                                var price = amount / count;
                                $("input[name=option" + (parseInt(i) + 1) + "]").val(price);
                            });
                        }

                    });
                         $("#amount").keydown(function() {
                        var multipleValues = $("#multiple").val() || "";
                        var amount = $("#amount").val();
                        var aVal = multipleValues.toString().split(",");
                        var count = $("#multiple :selected").length;
                        if (multipleValues != "")
                        {
                               $.each(aVal, function(i, value)
                            {
                                var price = amount / count;
                                $("input[name=option" + (parseInt(i) + 1) + "]").val(price);
                            });
                        }

                    });



                });
                                </script>
                                </body>
                                </html>
```

Comment: where should validation fired ?

Comment: you asked about that static text box **(toal_price)** key up validation after enter all dynamic text box values...

Comment: @ManikandanSethuraju yes sir exactly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

working Demo: http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7a/3

Please check above link

Comment: is it possible to do that validation with jquery(on key up  validation)